# Как реализовать иконку корзины с количеством товаров в ней в Toolbar Android приложения

Tags: android

Добрый день, Коллеги. Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать вот такой функционал?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Приложение для интернет-магазина. Нужно сделать иконку корзины в которой показано сколько сейчас товаров в ней. У меня нет идей вообще как это сделать, как даже загуглить подобное)) Если кто такое делал - подскажите пожалуйста:
1. Каким образом это можно реализовать - при помощи меню или в разметку toolbar или AppBarLayout запихать? 
2. Может есть какие-то готовые методы?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть готовая библиотека [ActionItemBadge](https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-ActionItemBadge) или [аналогичные](https://github.com/search?q=android+badge).

Так же такой `View` можно реализовать самому, собрав из двух `ImageView` и поместив их в контейнер `FrameLayout`.

Comment: Если собрать самому, не работает нажатие на элемент. Реализовал через:    final MenuItem menuItemAddShoppingCart = menu.findItem(R.id.action_add_to_shopping_cart);


        menuItemAddShoppingCart.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {...};    Как это можно решить?