# Как добавить вспомогательную иконку с основной в меню ActionBar?

Tags: java, android

В теме вопроса под вспомогательной иконкой я подразумевал маленькую в правом нижнем углу основной. Вот пример: маленькая иконка с цифрой показывает количество оповещений:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спросить я хочу, естественно, как добавить эту маленькую иконку с цифрой и ещё запрограммировать, чтобы в зависимости от числа оповещений выводилась нужная иконка, но если Вы предложите решение, в котором вместо маленькой иконки - отрисованная средствами Java цифра в круге, то это тоже подойдёт (возможно, так даже и лучше).

---

*Обновление*

Попробовал решение **katso**; код из активити приводит к краху приложения.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

Я уже [сталкивался](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/565157/java-android-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-findviewbyid) с такой проблемой и на основе разъяснения

> Вызывается он при инициализации поля класса, инициализация полей
>   класса происходит при создании экземпляра класса перед вызовом его
>   конструктора. И всё это происходит задолго до вызова метода onCreate.

объявил переменные до метода `onCreate` и инициализировать их внутри него. Теперь такая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На всякий случай выкладываю полный код приложения. В качестве иконки `ic_bell` можно использовать любое изображение. Часть кода почему-то не отображается, но его можно скопировать из поля ввода, которое появляется при нажатии "исправить".

- **MainActivity.java**

  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
  import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  ```
  View count;
  TextView notifCount;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
      setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

      count = menu.findItem(R.id.badge).getActionView();
      notifCount = (TextView)count.findViewById(R.id.notif_count);
  }

  private int mNotifCount = 0;

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

      notifCount.setText(String.valueOf(mNotifCount));
      return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
  }

  private void setNotifCount(int count){
      mNotifCount = count;
      invalidateOptionsMenu();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      int id = item.getItemId();

      if (id == R.id.badge) {
          return true;
      }

      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
  ```

  }
- **menu_main.xml**

  ```
  <item android:id="@+id/badge"
      android:actionLayout="@layout/actionbar_notifitcation_icon"
      android:showAsAction="always"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_bell"
      android:title="@string/hotlist" />
  ```
- **actionbar_notification.xml**

  ```
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/image"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_bell"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"/>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/notif_count"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:minWidth="17dp"
      android:textSize="12sp"
      android:textColor="#ffffffff"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:background="@drawable/rounded_square"/>
  ```
- **rouded_square**

Comment: Добавить custom view вместо стандартного в Toolbar

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562637/177345

Comment: Почему вы не хотите использовать готовые библиотеки из моего комментария выше? Они оттестированные и реализация вашего вопроса займет пару минут от силы ..

Comment: Из-за того же самого дискомфорта, что и испытывают ярые противники сторонних библиотек. Конечно, если это такая вещь, как jQuery для JavaScript, то имеет смысл подключить, но подключать сторонние библиотеки под каждую кнопку как-то не айс...

Comment: В общем о их для того и делают, чтобы по 4 дня не сидеть над каждой кнопкой. Это всего лишь еще один класс-виджет, такой же, как стандартные (напр. из SDK или Support library). Что вы сами его когда-нибудь напишите, что подключите в проект готовый - результат одинаков, но дело конечно ваше.

Comment: Хорошо, уговорили, но с этой ошибкой, что в вопросе, надо разобраться. Если сейчас не понять причину, ещё где-нибудь всплывет.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Пункт меню

**menu/menu_actionbar.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/badge"
        android:title="@string/hotlist"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/actionbar_notifitcation_icon"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

layout кнопки

**layout/actionbar_notifitcation_icon.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton"
    android:layout_width="54dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:clickable="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_bell" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notif_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_square"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/image"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Фон бэйджа

**drawable/rounded_square.xml**

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    <solid android:color="#ffff0000" />
    <stroke android:color="#ff222222" android:width="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

В активити:

```
 private int mNotifCount = 1;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_actionbar, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.badge);
    View count = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    TextView notifCount = (TextView) count.findViewById(R.id.notif_count);
    notifCount.setText(String.valueOf(mNotifCount));
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private void setNotifCount(int count) {
    mNotifCount = count;
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

[image: пример]

Comment: Благодарю Вас за время потраченное на решение! Осталось две проблемы и уверен, оно заработает. 1) Android Studio требует создать метод `getSupportMenuInflater`. Какой он должен иметь вид? 2) Где Вы определили идентификатор `notif_count`?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu обновил код, посмотрите. `getSupportMenuInflater()` заменил на `getMenuInflater()`, метод доступный в `AppCompatActivity`; `notif_count` - это `TextView` в `layout'e`

Comment: Прошу прощения за длинную паузу; к сожалению не мог протестировать Ваше решение два дня. К сожалению, Ваш код из активити приводит к краху приложения. Если Вам не трудно, посмотрите пожалуйста обновление вопроса.

Comment: @Gurebu Bokofu, покажите, стектрейс ошибки.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, обновил ответ. Заменил notifСount на notif_count, должно работать. Учитесь читать логи, в них написано по какой причине и в какой строке ошибка.

Comment: Попробовал Ваше решение в новом приложении, чтобы понять, конфликтует ли оно с моим кодом. Не вышло, ошибки те же. Опубликовал код приложения в вопросе.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, киньте архив проекта, я погляжу

Comment: Да не вопрос... ([ссылка](https://yadi.sk/d/3GgWza5NwdNww))

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, исправил ответ, проверяйте, все работает

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46621/discussion-between-katso-and-gurebu-bokofu).