# Текст поверх иконки. ActionBar menu

Tags: android, android-toolbar, actionbar, toolbar, android-menu

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом возможно добавить в Toolbar текст поверх иконки в меню? (как показано на картинке)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562637/177345 - большинство таких библиотек позволяет выводить не только числа, а произвольный текст или самому совместить в FrameLayout ImageView и TextView

Answer (score 2):

Нужно добавить в `<item>`, который находится в menu.xml `app:actionLayout`

```
  <item
        android:id="@+id/action_basket_tool"
        android:title="@string/action_basket"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/basket"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/toolbar_badge"
        />
```

После чего нужно создать данный лейаут,вот пример:

```
<FrameLayout
    style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <ImageView
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/basket"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cart_badge"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_width="8dp"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|end|top"
        android:background="@drawable/badge_background"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

Функция для работы с текстом

```
int count = 100;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gifts, menu);
        final MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_basket_tool);
        if(menuItem!=null) {
            actionView = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
        TextView view = actionView.findViewById(R.id.cart_badge)
            if(count > 0){
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                view.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            } else{
                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Когда данные обновились нужно просто вызвать

```
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

И оно пересоздаст этот пункт меню с новыми значениями или скроет его как у меня в примере

Comment: Подскажите, а откуда взялся actionView?

Comment: @Valeriy это глобальная переменная, я ее использую не только в этом методе, тут только инициализирую

Comment: Я использовал View view, правильное ли такое решение? И почему то перестала нажиматься не только эта иконка, но и соседняя.

Comment: @Valeriy вообще правильное, но сложно сказать без полного кода

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста, по возможности. https://github.com/Leeeeerich/MyShop/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/guralnya/myshop/MainActivity.java

Comment: @Valeriy проверь в дебаге проходит ли инициализация меню вообще?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80916/discussion-between-valeriy-and-toper).